# Not working on Chrome devtool console.log or alert()

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

On my html file I have javascript on it. Trying to pop a question with alert() and found out it doesn't work and trying to console log the question I see this message.
"Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform"

I will be glad to get some advice. I uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it but the same issue is still persisting.
Thanks

Comment: These messages are unrelated. Note that `alert` won't work in an active tab. A site can also overwrite `window.alert` - type `alert` without parentheses and run it - a native function will have `[native code]` inside. If that's not the case you need to add an MCVE to the question to make it answerable e.g. the URL of the site.

Comment: I understand they are unrelated, was just trying to debug my page and realized they were not working. The thing is they work on firefox and edge irrespective of tabs. Am simply trying to console.log('Hello man') and it won't log from the HTML file but will work if am working directly on the console. I think something is preventing the browser to log or to alert data from the html file.

Comment: Got it fixed. On my browser I clicked on the far end and went to setttings. Scrolled down to advance clicked and at the end I saw restore to original settings. After several minutes. I got back my browser nice and clean. Thanks